# Clicking on an img with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: Picture of HTML code]

I'm pretty new to coding in Python and in general.
So far, I've tried:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src,'/images/excel.png')])`

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector("/images.excel.png")`

`driver.execute_script("javascript: exportExcel('')")`

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='pageControl'][img/@src='/images/excel.png']").click()`

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Update:
[I've attached an additional image of the html code that is above the code depicted in the DOM in the previous image. There does not seem to be an iFrame obstructing the img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQT8r.png)

Update 2: I used pyautogui to physically move the mouse to a specified coordinate to click the icon on the page, as an alternative solution. So far, xpaths have failed to identify the element.

Comment: If I were to guess, this element is probably inside of an IFRAME or you need to add a wait.

Comment: Hello JeffC, thank you for your feedback. There doesn't seem to be an IFrame, and I've already included a time.sleep() function to input a delay.

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this by clicking on the parent `td` element. My understanding of your question is that you are trying to get the `excelExport()` function to trigger.

Using a CSS Selector:

```
td_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('td[onclick="javascript: excelExport()"]')
td_element.click()
```

The image itself could be selected with:

```
image = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('img[src="/images/excel.png"]')
```

Not tested (but it might work):

```
driver.execute_script("excelExport();")
```

When running `driver.execute_script`, the language does not need to be specified, as it will be javascript.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Brydenr. Your understanding of my question is correct. However, I get NoSuchElementExceptions when implementing your suggestions. The third suggestion also returns a JavascriptException error, where it states that excelExport is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen you attempt a Javascript click in your solutions yet, so let's try that. This is usually my catch-all for clicking on weird or funky elements.

```
image = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src,'/images/excel.png')]")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", image)
```

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Hello Christine, thank you for your feedback. This is the error message I receive executing your code:                                 
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//img[@src='/images/excel.png']"}
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.70)

Comment: Interesting, the XPath matches exactly as the element HTML appears. I changed my selector to use a contains query as mentioned in your example. Does that one throw an error, too? If so, there may be another element obscuring the `img`. Is there an `iframe` higher up in the DOM?

Comment: I've included the rest of the HTML above the previous image in the DOM. There doesn't seem to be an iframe. I appreciate your suggestion! However, it returned the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Click using the `Action` class:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table//tbody//tr//td[contains(@class,'pageControl') and contains(., 'Excel')]//img[contains(@src,'/images/excel.png')]")
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, frianH. I'm getting this error: "NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element"